# Is Producer request.timeout.ms honored when replica.lag.time.max.ms is higher?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have the following Producer configurations set, however, I am noticing that the `request.timeout.ms` does not play it's role when `replica.lag.time.max.ms` is higher and each request (RTT) seems to be waiting until the default value of 30 seconds -

```
retryBackOffMs: 25
retriesCount: 3
acks: 1 #Leader acknowledgment
lingerMs: 10
requestTimeOutMs: 300
```

Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to documentation (e.g. here: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-producer-ProducerConfig.html#request.timeout.ms):

> Property: request.timeout.ms
> This should be LARGER than replica.lag.time.max.ms (a broker configuration) to reduce the possibility of message duplication due to unnecessary producer retries.

But it is strange that it can affect request timeout...

There is another config as well: delivery.timeout.ms

(NB: The value of delivery.timeout.ms should be greater than or equal to the sum of request.timeout.ms and linger.ms)

Could you try to change it, maybe it helps in your situation? (But anyway, if replica.lag.time.max.ms is larger, you may encounter some problems such a duplicating messages, but maybe it is not critical for your application).

Answer (score 0):

In our application, we ended up adding delivery time out config and left the retries count unset to have Kafka retry as many times as is it determines and time out after the configured delivery time out, with sync produce to Kafka.

Answer (score -1):

The property `request.timeout.ms` is working as expected. Keep in mind that this is a client-side configuration whereas `replica.lag.time.max.ms` is a broker-side configuration. The relationship between them has to do with a best practice. It is expected that the `replica.lag.time.max.ms` should be higher than the value set on the property `request.timeout.ms` to reduce the possibility of message duplication due to unnecessary producer retries. But regardless your producer will always wait for the time configured on the property `request.timeout.ms`.

Comment: Thank you. `replica.lag.time.max.ms` is configured to be higher than `request.timeout.ms` I still see requests taking longer than the value configured for `request.timeout.ms` and only at times when there is an ongoing replica lag.

Comment: following the official documentation, it should be lower, not higher. "This should be larger than replica.lag.time.max.ms (a broker configuration) to reduce the possibility of message duplication due to unnecessary producer retries." See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_request.timeout.ms